# TensorFlow: Rerun network with a different input tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a typical CNN model in TensorFlow.

```
def inference(images):
    # images: 4D tensor of [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3] size.
    conv_1 = conv_layer(images, 64, 7, 2)
    pool_2 = pooling_layer(conv_1, 2, 2)
    conv_3 = conv_layer(pool_2, 192, 3, 1)
    pool_4 = pooling_layer(conv_3, 2, 2)
    ...
    conv_28 = conv_layer(conv_27, 1024, 3, 1)
    fc_29 = fc_layer(conv_28, 512)
    fc_30 = fc_layer(fc_29, 4096)
    return fc_30
```

A typical forward pass could be done like this:

```
images = input()
logits = inference(images)
output = sess.run([logits])
```

Now suppose my `input` function now returns a pair of arguments, `left_images` and `right_images` (stereo camera). I want to run `right_images` up to `conv_28` and `left_images` up to `fc_30`. So something like this

```
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3])
left_images, right_images = input()
conv_28, fc_30 = inference(images)
right_images_val = sess.run([conv_28], feed_dict={images: right_images})
left_images_val = sess.run([fc_30], feed_dict={images: left_images})
```

This however fails with

> TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object.
>   Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or
>   numpy ndarrays.

I want to avoid having to evaluate `inputs` to then feed it back to TensorFlow. Calling `inference` twice with different arguments will also not work because functions like `conv_layer` create variables.

Is it possible to rerun the network with a different input tensor?

Comment: I am not sure how the "images" is declared. It is a tf.placeholder ? If not, it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tensorflow shared Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html) is what you are looking for. Replace all calls of `tf.Variable` with `tf.get_variable()` in inference. Then you can run:

```
images_left, images_right = input()
with tf.variable_scope("logits") as scope:
    logits_left = inference(images_left)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    logits_right = inference(images_right)
output = sess.run([logits_left, logits_right])
```

Variables are not created again in the second call of inference. Left and right images are processed using the same weights. Also check out my [Tensorflow CNN training toolkit](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/tensorflow_toolkit) (Look at [training](https://github.com/TensorVision/TensorVision/blob/master/bin/tv-train) code). I utilize this technique to run validation and training forwards in the same TensorFlow graph.

Comment: FYI your `train.py` link is broken.

Comment: Does not include relevant content anymore due to modifications. Protip: always include the [commit SHA](https://github.com/TensorVision/TensorVision/blob/25b2f634550d12987f247ac1d0c5db6824bb8c81/bin/tv-train) in Github links