# Tensorflow graph with multiple inputs wihtout tf.placeholder for validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I use the `tf.data` API for my models. For now I define the output of the `tf.data` iterator as input for my network. After I got rid of the `feed_dict` method, my performance increased significantly.

Now I want to implement a validation set that runs at least after each training once. Is there a way to implement a validation run for `tf.data` or do I have to set a placeholder and manually switch the tf.datasets and use `feed_dicts` again? What is the recommended way for validation tests?

Comment: This is very similar to [this question posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52591657/1782792), see if it covers your case and whether the answer I wrote helps (otherwise please point out what would we different in your case).

Comment: Both ways help me. Your older question and the one below. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The hack-ish way - node replacement

The most trivial way, although definitely not the most beautiful, would just be to use the node created by the `tf.data` API as an input to the feed_dict - this is because in Tensorflow you can replace the value of any node in the computation graph by feeding it's value directly to the feed_dict.

So this would be something like

```
batch_input = tf_train_data_foo()
validation_input = tf_validation_data_foo()

model = build_model(batch_input)
optimization_step = some_optimization_foo(model)

# Regular train
session.run(optimization_step)

# Validation run
validation_data = session.run(validation_input)
session.run(model, {batch_input: validation_data})
```

## The better way - variable reuse

If all the construction uses `tf.get_variable` instead of creating new variables, and the scopes are all set to enable obtaining an existing variable, you can just call your `build_model` function twice - once with the train data (from `tf.data`) and once with your validation data. You can see more details on variable re-use on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36184935/748102)